# Are there typescript definitions for the kotlin standard library?

Tags: typescript, kotlin-js

Are there typescript definitions for the kotlin standard library?

I found the standard library on github, but am unable to find the typescript definitions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kotlin

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your use-case? What for do you need to import the "kotlin" package into JS/TS?

Comment: My colleague was trying to access types from the kotlin standard library that don't exist in javascript/typescript.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have JS library written in Kotlin and some API from it, which you want to call, uses types from stdlib?

Comment: Yes. Think about types like Kotlin Long that don't exist in JS/TS. After playing with Kotlin/JS.

Comment: There is no such definitions, but it could be interesting for you that the new JS (IR) compiler able to generate d.ts file for exported API, for more details check out https://kotl.in/jsir